# Rails join table name doesn't match migration or schema (PG::UndefinedTable: ERROR: relation does not exist)

Tags: ruby-on-rails

In my Rails project with a Postgres database, I have a user and workspace model. They are associated by a many to many relationship (`users_workspaces`). If I open up my rails console and try to get all user workspaces with `UserWorkspace.all`, I get the following 'relation does not exist' error:

```
2.5.1 :001 > UserWorkspace.all
Traceback (most recent call last):
ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid (PG::UndefinedTable: ERROR:  relation "user_workspaces" does not exist)
LINE 1: SELECT  "user_workspaces".* FROM "user_workspaces" LIMIT $1
                                         ^
: SELECT  "user_workspaces".* FROM "user_workspaces" LIMIT $1
2.5.1 :002 >
```

I don't understand why it's looking for `user_workspaces` (`user` being singular) rather than `users_workspaces` (both names plural). I'll looked through my codebase to see if this is in fact set somewhere as `user_workspaces`, but can't find it. I've also run `rails db:drop db:create db:migrate`, but still no luck. Here are related files, but I'm not sure where is issue is originating from.

**user model**

```
class User < ApplicationRecord
  has_secure_password

  has_and_belongs_to_many :workspaces

  validates_presence_of :username, :email, :password, :subscription_plan
  validates_uniqueness_of :username, :email
  validates_length_of :username, :within => 3..40
  validates_length_of :password, :within => 8..100
end
```

**workspace model**

```
class Workspace < ApplicationRecord
  has_and_belongs_to_many :users

  validates_presence_of :name
  validates_presence_of :admin_id
end
```

**user_workspace model**

```
class UserWorkspace < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :workspace

  validates_presence_of :user, :workspace
end
```

**schema.rb**

```
ActiveRecord::Schema.define(version: 2018_07_28_040836) do

  # These are extensions that must be enabled in order to support this database
  enable_extension "plpgsql"

  create_table "users", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string "username", null: false
    t.string "email", null: false
    t.string "first_name"
    t.string "last_name"
    t.string "password_digest"
    t.integer "subscription_plan", default: 0, null: false
    t.integer "current_workspace"
    t.datetime "created_at", null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
    t.index ["username"], name: "index_users_on_username", unique: true
  end

  create_table "users_workspaces", id: false, force: :cascade do |t|
    t.bigint "user_id", null: false
    t.bigint "workspace_id", null: false
    t.index ["user_id", "workspace_id"], name: "index_users_workspaces_on_user_id_and_workspace_id"
    t.index ["workspace_id", "user_id"], name: "index_users_workspaces_on_workspace_id_and_user_id"
  end

  create_table "workspaces", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string "name", null: false
    t.text "description"
    t.integer "admin_id"
    t.datetime "created_at", null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
  end
end
```

**users migrations**

```
class CreateUsers < ActiveRecord::Migration[5.2]
  def change
    create_table :users do |t|
      t.string :username, null: false, index: {unique: true}
      t.string :email, null: false, unique: true
      t.string :first_name
      t.string :last_name
      t.string :password_digest
      t.integer :subscription_plan, null: false, default: 0
      t.integer :current_workspace

      t.timestamps
    end
  end
end
```

**workspaces migration**

```
class CreateWorkspaces < ActiveRecord::Migration[5.2]
  def change
    create_table :workspaces do |t|
      t.string :name, null: false
      t.text :description
      t.integer :admin_id

      t.timestamps
    end
  end
end
```

**users_workspaces (join table) migration file**

```
class CreateJoinTableUsersWorkspaces < ActiveRecord::Migration[5.2]
  def change
    create_join_table :users, :workspaces do |t|
      t.index [:user_id, :workspace_id]
      t.index [:workspace_id, :user_id]
    end
  end
end
```

Any and all help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Out of curiosity, should `class UserWorkspace` be `class UsersWorkspace`?

Comment: Your class name is "UserWorkspace" so it'd look up for a relation call "user_workspace". Try pluralizing the class name (UsersWorkspace) as pointed out by @jvillian

Comment: In your model you can also specify `self.table_name = ` if absolutely necessary.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As mentioned in `schema.rb` table is created by the name `users_workspaces` and your class name is `UserWorkspaces`.

By default, rails try to infer the table name for a Model by its class name.

So, If classname is `UserWorkspace` then its corresponding table_name will be `user_workspaces` and not `users_workspaces`.

Now, You have two options either rename your model or somehow mention in your model that the table you want to use for this model.

Option-1
**Rename Model**

```
class UsersWorkspace < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :workspace

  validates_presence_of :user, :workspace
end
```

Option-2
**Allow `UserWorkspace` model to point to `users_workspaces` table**

```
class UserWorkspace < ApplicationRecord
  self.table_name = 'users_workspaces'
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :workspace

  validates_presence_of :user, :workspace
end
```

**UPDATE**

In addition to above in `UserWorkspace/UsersWorkspace` Model you don't need

`validates_presence_of :user, :workspace`

as since you are using rails 5.2, therefore, rails itself adds `presence` validation along with `belongs_to` association unless you have pass `optional: true` argument or you have declared it in the following way in `application.rb`

`Rails.application.config.active_record.belongs_to_required_by_default = false`